# Lists in Django templates not working as expected

Tags: python, django, list, templates

If looping through my users' groups in a profile view to insert different chunks of the page, but for some reason they aren't equating like I expect them to.  Here's the template:

```
{{ user_groups }}

{% for g in user_groups %}
    {{ g }}
    {% if g == "client" %}
        client things
    {% endif %}

    {% if g == "guardian" %}
        guardian things
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}

{% for group in request.user.groups.all %}
    {{ group }}
    {% ifequal group "guardian" %}
        this is a guardian
    {% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}

{% if "guardian" in user_groups %}
     Give me some guardian stuff
{% endif %}
```

*Output:* 
[<Group: guardian>] guardian guardian

---

As you can see I've done this both with the actual user object and with a list passed into context[].  In both cases the list itself has no issue iterating.  Both loops show the raw variable output, but the equals operations are failing.

I CAN make it do comparisons like `{% ifequal "something" "something" %}` which will show me the content inside the if block, but comparing a list element to a string just doesn't seem to be working any way I try to get it done.

I know I can't declare the list inside the if block, but in no case am I doing that.  Any thoughts on why this would be failing?  Did I miss something trivial?

Comment: What about `{% ifequal group.name "guardian" %}`?

Comment: That works.  Why the heck does that work?  Also, how would that affect the if foo in bar statement (as opposed to a for loop)?

Comment: Is it possible that `ifequal` actually converts `group` to a string while `==` doesn't implicitly do so?

Comment: You need to use `group.name`, since you want to compare the name of the `group`, not `group` object.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#ifequal

That's the docs for 1.6, which explicitly shows the string comparison.  Why is `.name` of any value here is my question.  I'm still new to python in general so it's possible I'm missing something minute, but important.

Comment: Ah I see.  So this is a dict of objects, not a list.  I was thinking it was a list of strings.  

Is it possible then to do if foo in bar with this then, or must I loop through?

Comment: It's still a list, it's not a dictionary, but of django model objects not of strings. If you pass a non-string object as a template variable (like `{{ group }}`) then django will try to print a string representation of the object (`[<Group: guardian>] guardian guardian` in your case). This is why your comparison has to be done with the specific object attribute (`.name`). If you want to avoid the loop, you need to first create a list of group names as strings and pass that to your template context instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `{{ group }}` implicitly converts the `group` object to a string, calling it's `__unicode__` or `__str__` method (depending on your python version). In the case of a user group, this will most likely return a string containing the value of `group.name`.

However, this implicit conversion does not take place in an `if` statement (and it shouldn't). Thus, the String `"guardian"` can never be equal to the Group object `guardian`.

I'd recommend to get this logic into your view rather than your template, where you can use more functions and do actual filtering:

```
def myview(request):
    context['is_guardian'] = request.user.groups.filter(name='guardian').exists()
    context['is_client'] = request.user.groups.filter(name='client').exists()
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', context)
```

And your template:

```
{% if is_guardian %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the analysis.  I ended up doing something slightly different than your suggestion in that I still used groups.all() to built the list and am using `if in` in the template.  It saves on database hits.